# Prove that the following function is differentiable (Spivak's book)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, alternative-proof, solution-verification

This question was already asked in the following link:

[Proving Differentiability of a Function (Spivak)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3257074/proving-differentiability-of-a-function-spivak)

But I tried to do it by myself and I had some doubts that I would like to be clarified.

The question says

> Let $g$ be a continuous, real-valued function on the unit circle, such that $g(-x)=-g(x)$ and $g(0,1)=g(1,0)=0$. Now define $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
>   $$
> f(x) =\begin{cases}
> \|x\|\cdot g\Big(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big) & x\neq 0
> \\ 0 & x=0
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   fix $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and define $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $h(t)=f(tx)$. Show that $h$ is differentiable.

It is not difficult to see (after considering the cases) that $h(t)$ has the following form:
$$
h(t) =
t\cdot\|x\|\cdot g\Big(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big)
$$
And from there it's obvious that $h'(t)=f(x)$. But before I was thinking in solve the problem without considered the cases where $t$ it's positive or negative (no directly) as do the guy in the question. instead I defined the function $I:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by 
$$
I(t) =\begin{cases}
1 & t >  0
\\ -1 & t<0
\end{cases}
$$ 
And write $h$ as
$$
h(t) =\begin{cases}
|t|\cdot\|x\|\cdot g\Big(I(t)\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big) & t\neq 0
\\ 0 & t=0
\end{cases}
$$
If we differentiated $h$ we respect to $t$ have that the derivative has the form
$$
h'(t)=
\dfrac{t}{|t|}\cdot\|x\|\cdot g\Big(I(t)\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big)+|t|\cdot\|x\|\cdot g_t\Big(I(t)\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big)\cdot I'(t)\\=\dfrac{t}{|t|}\cdot\|x\|\cdot g\Big(I(t)\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big)\\=I(t)\cdot\|x\|\cdot g\Big(I(t)\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big)\\= \|x\|\cdot g\Big(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big)=f(x)
$$ 
If $t\neq0$ and for the case where $t=0$ we can calculate the derivative of $h$ by definition and get that $h'(t)=f(x)$.

I know that is easier if I just notice that the fuction $h$ has the form $h(t)=t\cdot f(x)$. But my first idea was do it like this and now I have the doubt of how can I be sure that $\dfrac{d}{dt}g\Big(I(t)\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big)$ exist.

So this is my question.

> When can we know that a continuous function $g:S^1\to\mathbb{R}$ have a derivative with respect to $t\in\mathbb{R}$? i.e, When the derivative of $g\left(\dfrac{t}{|t|}\cdot\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\right)$ with respect to $t$ exist?

I know that is basically the same as the exercise but i would like to know is there exist a general way to do this and if it isn't exist in general, i would like to know if there is a way to be sure that in the case of this $g$ the derivative exist.

Comment: $g$ has no derivative with respect to $t$ because $g$ is not even defined with respect to a variable $t$. In fact, since $g$ is only defined on the unit circle, when you consider $g(tx)$, this requires that $t = 1/\|x\|$, so you are not free to vary $t$ and thereby take a derivative of $g(tx)$ with respect to $t$. Anyway, all that is known about $g$ other than symmetry and a couple values is that it is continuous. There is no guarantee it will be differentiable in any direction.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I've already edited the question. I suppose that the answer is the same. I had the doubt because it's the same thing you do with the function $f$ and because the only thing you're doing is multiplied by $t$ wherever the variable $x$ appears. could you give a counterexample to my question?

Comment: Well, that made a difference, but not a particularly useful one! $$g\left(\dfrac{t}{|t|}\cdot\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\right) = \begin{cases} g\left(\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\right), & t > 0\\\text{undefined}, & t = 0\\ g\left(-\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\right), & t< 0\end{cases}$$ Since these are constant with respect to $t$, the derivative of $g\left(\frac{t}{|t|}\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)$ exists and is $0$ for all $t \ne 0$. (Note that this is the derivative of the entire expression - not $g$!)

Comment: However, your write-up is still false, as there is no such thing as $g_t$. $g$ is not a function of $t$. $g$ is a function of the the points of $S^1$. When we want to parametrize the circle, we usually do it by angle - most commonly $\theta$. So it would make sense to talk about $g_\theta$. If you wrote it that way, your calculation would be correct when $g_\theta$ exists. But since we cannot expect it to exist, your calculation as written is wrong. You cannot fall back on the chain rule here. However, you can note as in my previous comment that the expression is nearly constant with $t$.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you!